# Software to help inventory set

Tags: software, inventory

Are there any software applications to help check the inventory of a lego set?

Currently I load the set-up as a bricklink wanted list and then delete each part one by one until I have only the missing parts left. This works okay but can be a bit cumbersome when checking about a hundred sets.

Answer (score 3):

I have had the same problem there are 2 ways you could do it.

**Way One is to use [rebrickable](http://rebrickable.com/home)**

1. Go to http://rebrickable.com/home Create an account.
2. Then go MYREBRICKABLE and select My Sets.
3. Then click Add set to this set list and search for the set you want.
   Now you can add all the sets you have.
4. IF you like you can go to the My Parts section and add any parts you
   might have bought.
5. Now if you want to find out how many red 2 x 2 bricks you have you
   can simply go to My Parts. Then tick the tick box where it says 'Set
   Parts' and click update. All your parts from your MY Sets and My
   Parts will now be shown below. You can see and example of this below.

[image]

**Way two is to use  [brickstock](http://brickstock.patrickbrans.com/) .**

1. So what I do is open brick stock.
2. Then Click Import and chose Bricklink Inventory.
3. Search for the set I want and then click ok. It
       then will create a file listing all the parts that make up the
   set(You will see a small hard hat icon at the top right as it
   download all the part images).
4. Do this for all your sets and combine the files and you will have
   one master file.